# iOS Set UITableView Expanded Initially

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView which has expandable custom cells. Multiple cells can be expanded. For that I have an array expandedArray in which I store the indexPath of all cells that are expanded. Initially all cells are collapsed. I want in initial start all cells to be expanded. This is my cellForRowAtIndexPath code :-

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

//  VISITORS LISTS TV
NSUInteger count = 0;

VisitorsListsCell *vcell = (VisitorsListsCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"VisitorsListsCell"];

if (vcell == nil) {
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"VisitorsListsCell" owner:self options:nil];
    vcell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
// Button - Round Corners
[vcell button].layer.cornerRadius = 5;
[vcell button].contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;

NSString *text = [visistorsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
// SET PROPERTIES OF CELL
// ....

if ([expandedArray containsObject:indexPath]) {
    // Do expanded cell stuff
    [vcell setButtonText:[visistorsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] withCount:(int)count isExpanded:YES];
    [vcell.button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrowup.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
} else {
    [vcell setButtonText:[visistorsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] withCount:(int)count isExpanded:NO];
    [vcell.button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrowdown.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
}

[[vcell listsTableView] reloadData];

return vcell;
}
```

I want is when the page is loaded, all cells are expanded. I believe for that I need to add indexPath of each cell to expandedArray. But on initial run only, how do I add the indexPath ??? I can't find a way to implement it.

Is it possible, any clue. OR any other way to achieve the goal. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: do you want to expand your first cell at reload tableView..?

Comment: why -viewDidLoad, -viewWillAppear or property getter (if _expandedArray == nil then) is not a good place to fill self.expandedArray?

Comment: @Szu, viewDidLoad...Appear ... are good places. I am wondering how can I get indexPath to fill in expandedArray. And I want to add it only once, so all cells are expanded, then let user do his way. But on first, when page is loaded, how can I get and add indexPath's to the array ?? I am not getting this part of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add indexPath to your expanded array you should use code below. But much simpler way is to use the same methods that are used in `-numberOfSections` and `numberOfRowsInSection:`. Using tableView delegates is not a good way.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.expandedArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (int itSection=0; itSection<[self.tableView numberOfSections]; itSection++) {
        for (int itRow=0; itRow<[self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:itSection]; itRow++) {
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:itRow inSection:itSection];
            [self.expandedArray addObject:indexPath];
        }
    }
}
```

Btw: the correct way to implement cell from xib:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    ....
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([VisitorsListsCell class]) bundle:nil];
    [self.tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"VisitorsListsCell"];
}
```

Comment: perfect. Thanks a lot. Why are you registering nib with tableview in viewDidLoad method ? Then how do we use in other table delegate methods for creating cell.

Comment: If you register cell in viewDidLoad is like you add that cell inside tableView in interface builder. If you do that you no longer need to check if dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier return a nil value.